# Extended WPF Toolkit not showing String Collection in collection editor

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the Extended WPF Toolkit for their property editor. http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid

I have a few StringCollection objects defined in my settings file that are being shown as System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection rather than in a CollectionEditor.

Here is how I defined the property editor:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="SettingsGrid" SelectedObject="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}" IsCategorized="False">
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

is there additional setup required?

Comment: You may perhaps need to define a `TypeConverter` for the same, or add properties manually to the `PropertyGrid` instead of being auto generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample for specifying custom editor for `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` in `PropertyGrid`

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="SettingsGrid"
                   SelectedObject="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}"
                   IsCategorized="False"
                   xmlns:sp="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Specialized;assembly=System">
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
        <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition TargetProperties="{x:Type sp:StringCollection}">
            <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Header="(StringCollection)">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
        </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition>
    </xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

before specifying the editor

[image: before]

after specifying the editor

[image: after]

this sample may not be exactly demonstrating how you want to edit the collection, you may adjust the template as needed

Comment: So the XAML editor says you can't assign `TargetProperties="{x:Type sp:StringCollection}"` because it doesn't consider a StringCollection an IList, even though it is. But it still compiles and runs fine and I can see the string collection editor. Is it possible to add/remove rows from the editor while editing or can you only edit the existing values.

Comment: Firstly you may safely ignore the compiler's warning. Secondly to manipulate the collection in all possible ways like add remove etc you may perhaps create a user control and take full control of manipulation, or even some mvvm can help you here. 'value' in the binding refers to the string collection . Happy coding :-)